# WindowsCE dependencies problems evaporate with change in aritecture

Tags: c++, x86, embedded, arm, windows-ce

I'm currently have an issue in a project that I'm writing.

Please note I'm not a C++ developer, I've never worked in Visual Studio before. My brief forays into C have never been in windowsOS's, let alone CE.

S my issue is I open a project folder in embedded Visual C++, and when I build the executable, for ARM I get 4 warnings that have to with signed/unsigned mismatch that I'm willing to ignore since this software has been in production for a decade without that issue cropping up.

But when I build for x86 (literally all I do is adjust my build target to Advantech UNO2059 form ADAM6500), I get 11 link errors that call adam6500crtl.obj, which I originally figured would be a library file but its a file that is generated during compiling (I think).

Comment: It sounds like you're not linking in something from the device's SDK, though with so little to go on it difficult to say what might be missing.

Comment: The problem is I get one error code that tells me I have an unresolved symbol (LNK2019), which means I create an object but never define it which is an unresolved dependency problem.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got the build to be completed successfully and run.

Instead of opening the project from within embedded Visual Studio it needs to be opened by double clicking the project file, apparently this loads other files (idk honestly).

Secondly build for release for debug. Debug creates dependency errors while release doesn't.

Comment: For the second point it may be that the release version has some defines or other configuration that the debug one hasn't. VC++ keeps two separate configurations, one for debug and one for release and when you open the properties only the active one is selected, so it's easy to have different settings or, maybe, being missing some parameters like an additional library folder.